# End pipe when program returns more than 1 line

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe

I'm querying a mysql db for the name of a database by pattern. Currently my implementation looks like this:

```
include_databases=$(mysql --batch --skip-column-names --execute "SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'foo%'" \
    | paste -sd ",")
```

Which will rturn a comma separated list of database names that matched the pattern.

However, I actually only expect one database name to be returned and I think it would be better to error out when mysql returns a result with 2 lines.

Is there something like:

```
include_databases=$(mysql --batch --skip-column-names --execute "SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'foo%'" \
    | __error_if_two_lines__ )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `head` to extract the first line:

```
include_databases=$(… | head -n 1)
```

However this will silently ignore any further lines. You can use awk instead to return a different exit code if there are more lines:

```
include_databases=$(… | awk 'NR>1 {exit(2)} 1')
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo >&2 'mysql returned multiple lines! Aborting.'; exit 2;;
fi
```

Or, under `set -e`:

```
include_databases=$(… | awk 'NR>1 {print "mysql returned multiple lines! Aborting." >"/dev/stderr"; exit(2)} 1')
```

Alternatively, you can store the output in a variable, and test whether it contains a line break. (Note that the final newline from the command is not included in the command substitution.)

```
include_databases=$(…)
nl='
'
case $include_databases in
  *"$nl"*) echo >&2 'mysql returned multiple lines! Aborting.'; exit 2;;
esac
```

In ksh/bash/zsh, but not in plain sh, you can write this in a more compact way.

```
include_databases=$(…)
if [[ "$include_databases" = *$'\n'* ]]; then
  echo >&2 'mysql returned multiple lines! Aborting.'; exit 2;;
esac
```

Comment: Using `head` sounds like the most sensible thing to do, thanks for that suggestion. Was a bit stuck with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think `wc` is your friend. Use option `-l` to count lines, `-w` to count words. (see man page)

```
mysql --batch --skip-column-names --execute "SHOW DATABASES" | wc -w
```

shows the number of databases.

e.g. something like this

```
include_databases=$(mysql --batch --skip-column-names --execute "SHOW DATABASES")
numDB=$(echo $include_databases | wc -w)
[ $numDB -gt 1 ] && echo -n "$numDB dbs is more than "
echo "one db"
```

Hint:
You should improve this script, because it uses a lot of subsheels